# How to understand the Google Redirect URI correctly?

Tags: google-oauth

From [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0) page, it explains the meaning of "Google Redirect URI" is :

> Determines where the response is sent. The value of this parameter
>   must exactly match one of the values registered in the APIs Console
>   (including the http or https schemes, case, and trailing '/').

Not sure, whether this explanation is same as my think or not:

On my app (web application), it allow user to sign-in via Google (Assume, I registered a Google project with ClientID/secrete configured on my web-app, and on Google COnsole page the redirectURI is "http://bbc.co.uk" ).

After I login to Google successfully by my Google account, my Web-app login page will be redirected to "http://bbc.co.uk" as on Google RedirectURI ?

Answer (score 2):

Let me see if i cant explain this in a different way.

What would happen if you didn't have a redirect URI?

If you go to the Developer console and create a `Client ID for native application` by default the redirect URI

[image]

This will redirect the Authentication back to where ever it was request from.  In the case of native installed applications this is needed because there is no way to know where the user is that has installed the application.

**Lets look at this in action**

Request authentication:

> `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code`

If you place the above line in a web browser the user will see something like this

[image]

Assuming they select ok then they get this displayed back at them.

[image]

That is the Authentication code, not to be confused with the access token.  This is just the first step.  Once your application has the Authentication code it can then exchanged that for a refresh token and a access token. Most client library handle this step internally.  You and your users never see this Authentication code.

**Back Redirect URI:**

In the case if a web application your web application needs to be able to get a hold of that authentication code.  Now I probably shouldn't be telling you this but you could just use a native application client in your web application and it will work.  Why because the authentication server will just return the Authentication code back to where ever it was that requested it.  For security reasons this is probably a bad practice.

So what do you need to place in the redirect uri.  It is the file that you have ready to handle this authentication code.   Normally its just the same as the login page, but you can have several. Just put each of them on separate lines.

```
http://localhost/login.php
http://www.daimto.com/login.php
```

I like to do this because then it works when i am testing locally vs when its up on the server.

Comment: @DalmTo: thank for your comment, from your comments, I understand that the RedirectURI is just the place that Authentication code is sent to , NOT the page is redirected to, after user sign-in to Google successfully. So, which case Authorized Google RedirectURI page is loaded after sign-in ?

Answer (score 1):

That last sentence is a bit ambiguous. A better description is:

> After I login to my Google Account successfully with my Google
>   credentials, Google will redirect my browser back to
>   Redirect URI `http://bbc.co.uk` that is registered for the web app in the Google > API Console.

Just to be sure: this means that the Redirect URI should be part of your web app. It is not actually Google's Redirect URI but it is the Redirect URI that you've configured in the Google API Console for your web app.

Answer (score 1):

I think the wording "Determines where the response is sent" confuses a lot of beginners as it implies that Google will somehow call that URL directly. Then the word "redirect" leads people to confuse the URL with the page of the app that the user will get to once he's authenticated.

http://bbc.co.uk is definitely NOT the redirect URL. A redirect URL would normally look like https://myapp.com/servlet_or_php_that_i_wrote_to_process_tokens.php

Google will "call" servlet_or_php_that_i_wrote_to_process_tokens.php by redirecting the browser to it. Once servlet_or_php_that_i_wrote_to_process_tokens.php as done whatever is needed with the token, it will then issue its own redirect to (say) bbc.co.uk

Comment: could you please give me detailed examples ?

Comment: sorry for unclear comment, as you mentioned "https://myapp.com/servlet_or_php_that_i_wrote_to_process_tokens.php", could you please give me a real page or real web-site that after sign-in to Google, it's be redirected to other page different from Google Autho RedirectURI

Comment: you haven't said what language you are using. That should really be a separate question on SO as it's no longer related to OAuth. In essence you need to send a 302 status with a location header. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Comment: would you like to tell me which case the Authorized Google RedirectURI is loaded ?